# JavaScript Query Json String from (api.census.gov)

Tags: javascript, json, api

I have an API which should return some text JSon String.

http://api.census.gov/data/2010/sf1?get=P0010001&for=county:013&in=state:08

I wan to use JavaScript to query this API and display in the HTML element. The code looks like this:

```
   //html
   <input type="submit" value="Get City" onclick=" getpop()">
   //JS:
   function getpop() {
        var nereq2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        nereq2.open("GET", "http://api.census.gov/data/2010/sf1?get=P0010001&for=county:013&in=state:08", true);
        nereq2.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (nereq2.readyState == 4) {
                var temp3 = nereq.response;  **//problem start at here, which always return empty*******
                document.getElementById("fs").innerHTML = temp3;
            };
        };
        nereq2.send();
    }
```

When I click the link it returns the JSon properly, however when I use the code to query, it returns empty. I don't know whether it related to the browser setup or there are some other issues?

Comment: What do you mean use the code to query?

Comment: May be my wording is not correct, I mean use html "GET" to get the JSON string

Comment: are you seeing any error in console or in network. Probably you may see cross domain origin or insecure XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Do `nereq2.readyState == 4 && nereq.status == 200`

Comment: Here is error: Critical error was detected at line 14, column 17 in http://localhost:50127/index.html.
SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier

Comment: The request returns `[["P0010001","state","county"],
["294567","08","013"]]`. Is it what you want to show?

Comment: That means syntax error probably?

Comment: Yes that is what I want to get..

Comment: The `repsonse` property is empty because there is no such property. There are two properties containing the response body--`responseXML`, a parsed DOM document if the response was valid XML, and `responseText`, a string containing the raw output of the response body. The latter is what you should be attempting to parse.

Comment: @JAAulde `response` will return the same thing as `responseText` unless you set the `responseType` to something else.

Comment: @JAAulde I not really good at this? any code solution?

Comment: @4castle Intersting, I did not know that. Docs for those that also did not know: https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-response-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. `nereq.response` should be `nereq2.response`.

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scmh6Ln9/) - (*using https here because JSFiddle requires that*)

Comment: I was about to post the same. Plus one for you.

Comment: Since this is the answer, this question should technically be closed.